# Testrpc and Raspberry

Tags: testrpc

I have a Raspberry 3 where I should install an Ethereum node. My aim is ,substantially,demonstrate the ability to store data(some strings written in python on rpi) on blockchain. Since I had problems both with public and private testnet(cause I couldn't add ether to accounts),I would know if testrpc is enough for my purpose.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, Raspberry3 is capable of running a node but it will not be able to generate the DAG required to mine the blockchain.
Therefore, you need to connect the Raspberry3 to a network that include at least one other node mining (this of course include the live network).

Now, testrpc does not store physically any data and process new transaction almost instantly:

- Every time you will restart testrpc, the data will be gone. But this might be sufficient for your demonstration as you should be able to simulate your whole business case without restarting the process.
- In the real product, as mentionned above, you will have to include a connection to a network.

So it can work if the limitations above are acceptable for your project.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried once raspberry pi to send transaction to the testnet and the mainnet using the light client.

you could use [ethembded](http://ethembedded.com/?page_id=171)  and run geth using `--light` to avoid downloading the whole blockchain.

and while you are using pyton you will need to use the [web3.py](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py) to interact with your node and the blockchain from your python scripts.

Comment: mmm I have some conceptual problems...my professor suggested me to use node.js as wrapper(I dont know exactly what he meant).It takes data from python script (with a socket for example,since i would trasnfer data on the same device)and then interfaces with my node,storing data on blockchain...
So what is exactly node.js and why I need it if I can use web3 api from python too??

Comment: Nodejs is a run-time environment for executing JavaScript programs, so you could write a nodejs app which use the web3js.  you have the choice to use python only or using nodejs/web3js or if you have a specific reason use both of them interconnected.

Comment: So could I take data from an accelerometer and then send them(plus other strings like gps coordinate and date) to the blockchain with an unique script in python?

Comment: Yes you can if you can reaf already the data from it using pyyhon the rest is possible